# Winapi Printing text to the screen with TextOut

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm having a problem in this block of my code and I don't know what it is... at the TextOut line it says error:    initializing argument 4 of 'BOOL TextOutA(hdc, int, int, LPCSTR, int)' [-fpermissive]

This is what I found to do when trying to print text to a window and it isn't working, any help is greatly appreciated because I have been spending several hours trying to print a string to my window.

```
HDC hdc;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
TCHAR textString[] = _T("This is my message");

switch( message ){
    case WM_CREATE:
        Beep(1000,250);
        //Beep(523, 500);

        return 0;
        break;

    case WM_PAINT:

        hdc = BeginPaint( hwnd, &ps );

        TextOut( hdc, 5, 5, message, _tcslen(textString) );

        EndPaint( hwnd, &ps );
        break;
```

Comment: But `message` is not a string?

Comment: What type is `message`?

Comment: change message to textString. message is UINT [ LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) ]

Comment: The compiler told you what was wrong already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple bug.`message` is an integer denoting the windows message that was received. I think that what you intended was to output `textString` since you were referencing its length as `_tcslen(textString)` . Modify your textout line to be:

```
TextOut( hdc, 5, 5, textString, _tcslen(textString) );
```

Comment: wow I feel like an idiot I had named the string message earlier and then realized that message was already defined so I had to rename and replace it and I guess I just missed an instance of it.